# EndTime of a quartz scheduler job

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I've just started using quartz scheduler. I have a question regarding how do i get the final fire time of my scheduler. I used context.getTrigger.getEndtime but it retuns null. Please help

Answer (score 0):

See Job does not have like final fire time, Trigger have.

and with the help of your job's trigger you can get it, 
Trigger's getPreviousFireTime() method, [refer for more info](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getPreviousFireTime%28%29)

**UPDATED**

```
// before start trigger note time...

// at the end note time

// finally calculate startTime - endTime will get you time-duration how much time it takes,
```

then `add` this time-duration to `fire final`

**UPDATE-2 :**

follow this way,

insert into job's logic insert this type of things,

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
.....your program....
long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
```

// outside somewhere where you want to display..

```
Date lastRunTime = trigger.getFinalFireTime();

Date result = new Date(lastRunTime.getTime() + totalTime);
```

**getFinalFireTime()**

Comment: But i want the final time when the trigger will run. For eg. If I'm running the trigger from 11am to 2pm i want the end time i.e 2pm. I'm using my triggers function getEndTime but it returns null.

Comment: @Prakhar see there won't any direct method are then but you can apply logic likewise, see my UPDATED section

Comment: Ok got it. I will try this out and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: @Prakhar please if you are satisfied by answer then accept+upvote to my answer. thanks.

Comment: How do i note time when the trigger runs for the last time. Thats what i actually want.

Comment: @Prakhar see UPDATE-2 section.

Comment: I'm using spring to configure my scheduler. I have used cronExpression like 0 50-59 10 * * ? Now if a want the end time then it should return 10:59 as the last time the trigger will be fired. So i tried using context.getTrigger().getEndTime() but it's returning null.

Comment: i already told you use getPreviousFireTime- method not getEndTime()

Comment: if trigger haven't fired then it will sure return null because your job still not run at least one-time understand ?

Comment: But my job is running. If quartz has has orovided a method getEndTime then surely they must be calculating the last time the trigger will run.

Comment: Previous time will fetch me the previous run time not the last one.

Comment: @Prakhar correct then use getFinalFireTime() see i updated answer too.

Comment: Tried that also. Still returns null.

Comment: @Prakhar please post your whole code, or else you need to investigate much , now i can't help you anymore